# lua53.pas doesn't connect to the project

Tags: lua, lazarus

I try to use `lua` in my project. In my code System are mailing me error

> Compile Project, Target: Program: Exit code 1, Errors: 1
>   Program.lpr(14,3) Fatal: Syntax error, "BEGIN" expected but
>   "identifier INTERFACES" found

There is my code

```
program Program;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$linklib liblua53.dylib}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads, LUA_LIB_NAME,

  {$ENDIF}
      Classes, lua53;
  {$ENDIF}

  Interfaces, // this includes the LCL widgetset
  Forms, Unit
  { you can add units after this };
```

How I should to do it correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basic pascal syntax error: replace the ; after lua53 with a comma (,)

Comment: I'm still got an error but other. `Compile Project, Target: Program: Exit code 1, Errors: 1
ld: warning: ignoring file ./liblua53.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): ./liblua53.dylib

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
An error occurred while linking 
Program.lpr(24,32) Error: Error while linking
`

Comment: Exactly, running stopped at `Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1); `

Comment: Error linking means that the library and what you are compiling don't match. Usually you are trying to link something i386 (32-bit) to x86_64 (64-bit)